# How to test nested object with Chai and Mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I'm using mocha, chai, and chai-http to do integration testing for my Node.js and Express app. I'm trying to test out does my login route has token or not. I tried different asserts to check does token exist inside of data object but none of them work.

Data from Postman looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwiaWF0IjoxNTYzODczMzE3LCJleHAiOjE1NjM5NTk3MTd9.bM1RFem2pnlEqjTWGhg-s4Am1PjGNRUS_8x5Dq8J6lI",
    "user": {
      "id": 6,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "createdAt": "2019-07-23T06:38:11.358Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-23T06:38:11.358Z"
    }
  },
  "hasErrors": false,
  "errors": []
}
```

This is my actual test where I'm trying to check does res.body has nested token inside of data object.

```
/* Login Test */
let credentials = {
  'email': 'adnan@test.com',
  'password': 'test'
};

describe("POST /user-sessions", function() {
  it("should login user", function(done) {
    chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
      .post("/user-sessions")
      .send(credentials) 
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);

        res.body.should.have.nested.property('data.token');
        done();
      })
  });
})
```

I'm getting  Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (data, hasErrors, ...) } to have property 'data.token'

Answer (score 5):

I was using `expect` for assertion so it worked well using the below option:

```
expect(res.body).to.deep.nested.property('payload.products.changes');
```

The sample response from my API is as below:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "payload": {
    "products": {
      "changes": {
        "period": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: Works like a charm. How about if I need to where x is a list:  x[0].payload.products.changes ?

Comment: Yes, we could do that as well if we have to specifically asset the first element else we can iterate it and do the assertion. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `deep.property` to check the nested property in the object.

```
res.body.should.have.deep.property('data.token')
```